# «Франко невечен» — почему слитно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> Хорошо, что Памплона остается Памплоной, может, это самый верный залог того, что Франко **невечен**, что его режим, такой прочный в своей безнадежности и такой безнадежный в своей прочности...

Почему "невечен" слитно?

Comment: Вы бы ссылочку дали...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, это Нагибин, "Остров любви".
Я не уверен, что это авторский вариант написания. Если вы сверялись с бумажным источником, уточните, пожалуйста.

В принципе вариант слитного написания возможен, если на то есть явная воля автора, но здесь он совершенно не смотрится.
У меня бумажного нет, но я сильно подозреваю, что дело либо в случайной опечатке, либо в ошибочной оцифровке, размноженной потом по разным источникам.

Если же предположить, что это авторское написание, то, надо полагать, автор исходил из того, что (по его вИдению) здесь имеет место образование нового качества: невечен = смертен, преходящ. Я, как уже сказал, на месте автора на таком бы не настаивал. Но Нагибин имеет право.

Comment: Поиском по книгам находятся 4 издания с разным написанием, из них в самом старом (журнал "Знамя" 1979) написано раздельно - во всяком случае, гуглом так показывается распознанный текст, найденный по запросу слитного варианта ("Франко невечен Нагибин").

Comment: @Alex_ander okay, Тут действительно віглдядит весьма странным.